# Adding typescript typings to react components written in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a set of react components written in javascript and flow which I would like to add typings to support typescript. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this so any help would be appreciated.
Here's my project structure:

```
/
|_src
  |_index.js
  |_components
    |_index.js
    |_ComponentName
      |_index.js
      |_ComponentName.js
```

Comment: Do you want to auto-generate the `.d.ts` from your `.ts` files or maintain your own `.d.ts` files?

Comment: I don't have any `.ts` files yet, so I think maybe maintain my own for now.

Comment: I suggest reading the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) and also looking at DefinitelyTyped for real-life implementations. For example, [tape](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/tape) is short and sweet.

Answer (score 3):

Update

I've tried these approaches so far:

```
// inside ComponentName folder
// index.d.ts
// import {ComponentName} from '/path/to/ComponentName/folder'

import * as React from 'react';

export = ComponentName
export as namespace ComponentName;

declare namespace ComponentName {
  interface ComponentProps { }
  const ComponentName: React.SFC<ComponentProps> // for stateless functional components
}
```

Alternative #2

```
// inside ComponentName folder
// index.d.ts
// import ComponentName from "ComponentName";
declare module "ComponentName" { // play around with this ex: `projectName/ComponentName`
  import * as React from 'react';
  interface ComponentProps { }
  const ComponentName: React.SFC<ComponentProps>; // stateless fn component
  export default ComponentName; // play with this to suit your export flavor ex: export {ComponentName}
}
```

Test it works by creating a `.tsx` file and importing the components.
Needs more work for intellisense in editors but so far it shows missing props error.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t done this myself before but I came across this site that might help you: 
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-why-a-guide-to-using-typescript-with-react-fffb76c61614

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I don't really want to have to rewrite to typescript. I was thinking more like bundling `*.d.ts` files with the library.